# Showing Whether a Sequence is Bounded Above or Not

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction

I am trying to solve the following problem about a sequence:
Consider the sequence ${a_n}$ where $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac {1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} + \frac {1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7} + ... + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)}.$ Decide whether ${a_n}$ is bounded above or not, and prove your answer is correct.

I started to solve it in the following manner:
Let $a_n \geq a_{n+1} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)} \geq \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot (2n-1) \cdot 2(n+1)-1} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot (2n-1)} \geq \frac{1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot (2n-1) \cdot 2n+1}.$ Multiplying by the reciprocal of $a_n$, we have $1 \geq \frac{1}{2n+1}$ which shows that $a_n$ is increasing. 
This is where I am stuck since I do not know how to proceed in showing it is bounded from what I have so far. Any assistance or criticism is welcome.

I am using the following textbook: *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck.

Comment: Showing the sequence is increasing doesn't help in determining whether the sequence is bounded above or not. What you are trying to do is ascertain whether there is $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: It isn't clear what your sequence is supposed to be. Is the general term (for large enough $n$) supposed to be $$a_n=1+\frac1{1\cdot 3}+\frac1{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}+\cdots+\frac1{1\cdot 3\cdots(2n-1)},$$ or is it supposed to be $$a_n=1+\frac1{1\cdot 3}+\frac1{1\cdot 3\cdot 7}+\cdots+\frac1{1\cdot 3\cdots(2^n-1)}?$$

Comment: It is the first one. I believe I made a mistake by skipping the 5 in the denominator. Correction has been added in, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem. I though it worth double-checking. Incidentally, since the second version's sequence terms will be no greater than the first version's, then showing that the first sequence is bounded above will show that the second is bounded above, albeit indirectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$a_n\le 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\lt 2.$$

Comment: Is this method an example of using powers of 2 in order to get a lower estimate of the given sequence? We saw something like this in my class, and ended up with the natural logarithm which is not bounded above.

Comment: You probably know that the infinite **geometric** series $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$ has sum $2$. So definitely bounded above. You are probably referring to $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots$ (the **harmonic** series), which does diverge.

Comment: @Jamil_V: No. Finding a smaller sequence that is not bounded above is a way to show that a given sequence is not bounded above. This is finding a *larger* sequence that *is* bounded above, which shows that the given sequence is bounded above.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, I appreciate the input from everyone about my question.

Comment: You are welcome. As you saw, both answers replace the numbers in your series by numbers that are easier to handle, but still shrink fast enough for their sums to remain bounded.

Answer (score 8):

HINT: Let $b_n=\frac1{1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}$; for all $n\ge 1$ we have $b_{n+1}\le\frac13b_n$, so $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\le\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac13\right)^k\;.$$

Now use what you know about geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a direct proof that doesn't use geometric series outright, note that if you  consider the terms in $a_n$ shifted forward one position and then compare to the terms in $a_{n+1}$, you get $a_{n+1} \leq 1 + a_n/3$.  Also note $a_1 = 1 < 3/2$.  If $a_n < 3/2$ then $a_{n+1} \leq 1 + a_n/3 < 1 + 1/2 = 3/2$ as well. So the entire sequence is bounded above by $3/2$ by induction.

Comment: I am a bit familiar with this technique of shifting. However, how does it actually work? I have seen this before, but never fully grasped its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This may be informal, but just showing that the sequence is monotone decreasing would mean the first term is the upper bound for the sequence.

We may rewrite the sequence in the following way $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{2n+1}$. We can then see whether the sequence is infact monotone decreasing

$a_n-a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{a_n}{2n+1}=\frac{2na_n}{2n+1}$

We know $ n>0, ~a_n>0,~ 2>0,~2n+1>0$ which means

$\frac{2na_n}{2n+1}>0 \implies a_n>a_{n+1}$

This sequence is monotone decreasing and therefore is bounded inclusively by the first term of the sequence itself, which is 1.